# Differentiation of the fixed point of a function with respect to parameters, when the function is linear and invertible

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, computational-complexity, fixed-points

Consider a linear, differentiable, and invertible function $f_\theta:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, with parameters $\theta$, with exactly one fixed point $z_0 = f_\theta(z_0)$. At that fixed point, I'd like to calculate the set of derivatives $\frac{\partial z_0}{\partial \theta}$. Given the function's properties and the Jacobian inverse identity, $J_{f^{-1}}=J_f^{-1}$, is there a computationally efficient way to calculate $\frac{\partial z_0}{\partial \theta}$?

This problem has come up recently in my work. It's very similar to the problem approached in [1] (Supplement A, Theorem 1) and [2] (Section 2.1), which end up with the equation
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} [I-\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}]^{-1}$$ The main bottleneck here is solving $[I-\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}]^{-1}$. Because the full matrix inverse is $O(n^3)$, and n is large for practical problems, these references solve for this inverse with iterative methods like a Neumann Series[2].
In my problem, however, f is both linear and invertible, which I'm hoping could simplify or speed up the computational process of finding $\frac{\partial z_0}{\partial \theta}$.

For instance, $J_f^{-1}$ can be quickly calculated with the Jacobian inverse identity by simply differentiating $f^{-1}$, which for this function is computationally easy. Using this with the Woodbury identity [3] to find $[I-\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}]^{-1}$ doesn't appear to help with computational complexity, however, since the identity matrix is of course full rank and we thus must perform another full inverse. Is there another approach to the problem that I'm missing, or are the function's properties simply not helpful in this case?

Thanks for your help!

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.01377.pdf

[2] https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.05177.pdf

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: Idea: could approximate the fixed point by considering finite sequence of composites of $f_\theta$ with itself such that they converge to the fixed point. By limiting number of iterations, you get an approximation of the fixed point. Computing derivatives for the approximation is likely easier than for the fixed point, but you need some strategy for what to do if iterations are not sufficient.

Comment: @EsaPulkkinen An interesting point! This reminds me of the "Unrolling-based Phantom Gradient" in equation (16) of reference [2]. For my particular use case, in which f simulates wave propagation, it appears to me that these methods unfortunately don't simplify the problem much, as the fixed point would require a great deal of compositing to approximate.

Comment: I was thinking of domain theory approach to fixed point computation. My reference is  Roy L. Crole: Categories for Types. Could be a bit heavy for this purpose though.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into it. Thanks!